# How would you reshape a collection of images from numpy arrays into one big image?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having some trouble reshaping a 4D numpy array to a 2D numpy array. Currently the numpy array is follows, (35280L, 1L, 32L, 32L). The format is number of images, channel, width, height. Basically, I have 35280 image blocks that are 32x32 and I want to combine the image blocks (keeping the indices) to create one big image.

Comment: What's supposed to be the shape of the 2d array?  What do you mean by `keeping the indices`?

Comment: How do you want to combine the image blocks?

Answer (score 3):

Reshaping is not sufficient, you must carefully rearrange your data with `swapaxes`.

Sample data :

```
dims=nbim,_,h,w=np.array([6,1,7,6])
data=arange(dims.prod()).reshape(dims)%256
```

The images :

```
figure()
for i in range(nbim):
    subplot(1,nbim,i+1)
    imshow(data[i,0],vmin=0,vmax=255)
```

[image]

and the big image :

```
#number of images in each dim :
nh = 2 # a choice
nw=nbim // nh

bigim=data.reshape(nh,nw,h,w).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(nh*h,nw*w)
figure()    
imshow(bigim)
```

[image]

Comment: and you should probably mention something about fortran vs c order

Comment: Ok for `matshow`, next time. I think that all images format are 'C'-aligned today, so speaking fortran layout here will add confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array like this:

```
images = np.random.randint(0,256,(35280, 1, 32, 32))
```

The first thing you need is to figure out (somehow) what the width of the final image is supposed to be.  Let's say for this example that it's `(441 * 32, 80 * 32)`.

Then you can do:

```
image = images.swapaxes(0,2).reshape((441 * 32, -1))
```

This gives you almost what you need, except the rows are interleaved, so you have:

```
AAABBBCCC
DDDEEEFFF
GGGHHHIII
AAABBBCCC
DDDEEEFFF
GGGHHHIII
```

You can then use "fancy indexing" to rearrange the rows:

```
image[np.array([0,3,1,4,2,5])]
```

Now you have:

```
AAABBBCCC
AAABBBCCC
DDDEEEFFF
DDDEEEFFF
GGGHHHIII
GGGHHHIII
```

I will leave as an exercise the part where you generate the fancy indexing sequence.